# how to use vue-resource and proxy.php to solve the cross domain problem

Tags: php, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

First of all. I want to take a few words to explain that I am fully aware of what Cross-domain problem is and how to deal with it (in plain js with jQuery, but not in vue)

Here is the case:
I want to get the WFS features (as xml) from some of the geoserver (other domains) using the **HTTP GET request**. It is clear that it will be blocked because of the same origin policy.

I used to use a very simple proxy.php file to go around this and it works pretty well.

The proxy.php file is like this:

```
<?php
$nix="";
$type=$_GET['requrl'];
if ($_GET['requrl'] != $nix) {
    $file = file_get_contents($_GET['requrl']);
} else {
    $file = "false type";
}
echo $file;
?>
```

So basically I write in JS an Ajax-call with jQuery. which looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax(
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        requrl: "www.example.com/WFS?service=wfs&request=GetCapabilities"
    },
    url: "proxy.php"
).done(function (response) {
    // handle the response text/xml
    console.log(response);
})
```

The old way works well, I send the **"true" url** as **requrl** to the php file, the php get what I want for me and return it as response. So I can later hanlde the response with the jQuery-ajax.

---

**The real problem:**

But now I am moving my whole app to the vue.js framework. So **I am now using vue-resource instead of the jQuery-ajax**.

The vue-resource is not hard to understand. So I make the HTTP GET request as below:

```
this.$http.get('/static/proxy.php', {params: {requrl:"www.google.de"}}).then(response => {
    // success
    console.log("oh! success!");
}, response => {
    // error
    console.log("oh! error!");
});
```

I placed the proxy.php file in the public/static folder and the vue-resource keeps **getting the content of the proxy.php for me**. But not go through it and retrun me the response.

I have checked the HTTP GET request with the firefox dev tools and it shows me that the GET request is 200 OK. But the response is always the content of that proxy.php. It seems like **the php file is not doing the work that I expected it to do.**

And here is the response I got from the vue-resource GET request:

```
<?php $nix=""; $type=$_GET['requrl']; if ($_GET['requrl'] != $nix) {    $file = file_get_contents($_GET['requrl']); } else {    $file = "false type"; } echo $file; ?>
```

I am kind of knowing that the dev server could be the reason because in old days, I have php installed in my apache local server, and now with vue.js. I just type **npm run serve** each time I want to start a dev server. **I don't know what kind of dev server I just started and if it works with php.**

**So I would like to ask how u guys deal with vue-resource and php. Or maybe there is a better way in vue.js to go around the cross domain problem?**

Here is the dev environment I am using now:
The project is created with vue.js and vue/cli 3 (contained webpack and etc.)
The plug-in I use is vuetify and vue-resource

---

**For those who maybe search for the same question in the future. I have solved my question this way:**

1. Set up an apache server, by which php is installed (I got the content of my proxy.php because of that **I didn't have php installed in the dev server, which is started by the command npm run serve, and that was why it didn't work!**)
2. Make sure that you enable the **CORS** on your apache server! Because this apache server will run at an different port (for example 8888) and your dev server for your vue app will run for example at 8080 as default! And different ports will be considered also as Cross Domain! **So make sure to enable the CORS on your apache server!**
3. Point your HTTP GET Request to your proxy.php file in your apache server with vue-resource, here an example in vue app **(my apache server is running at port 8888, the proxy.php file is also showed in this question, here I got my own ID with the GET Request to the url http://httpbin.org/ip):**

   ```
       this.$http.get('http://localhost:8888/proxy.php', {params: {requrl: "http://httpbin.org/ip"}}).then(response => {
           // success
           console.log("oh! success!");
           console.log("success response: ", response);
       }, response => {
           // error
           console.log("oh! error!")
           console.log("error response: ", response);
       });
   ```
4. Now you successfully go around the Cross Domain!

Comment: Have you tried dumping $_REQUEST just to make sure that $_GET has not been unset somehow, I have experienced this happen once in the past where $_GET is cleared out because someone made a mistake with a XSS prevention parser..

Comment: @Marc Newton Thanks for your advise but I don't really think this is the problem here. Can I ask how you go around with the cross domain problem?

Comment: Is the console printing you an error? Can we see it?

Comment: I just been battling CORS with nginx last couple of days and one thing I have found today is that despite setting any CORS related headers in PHP, the httpd layer apache/nginx can block access before PHP is even processed, so consider that for a moment firstly.

Comment: Technically everyone does what you are doing now with proxy.php only diff is that most php applications forces all requests to be parsed through index.php useing httpd based url Rewrite where you can declare cross domain allow headers.
For debugging on localhost i always use wildcard * allow all. Then make sure httpd (apache/nginx etc) is not blocking the http request before PHP can set the desired header headers, else configure all headers in Apache or whatever your using rather than trying to set them in PHP.

Comment: @AngelRoma The console does not print any error. The HTTP GET Request has a status code 200 OK. The weird part is, the response of the request is the text content of my proxy.php. So I highly doubt about that the dev server which I started with npm run serve is not capable of dealing with PHP files.

Comment: If your seeing the source code for proxy.php then you not installed or setup php correctly. also `npm run serve` wont start php-fpm will it?.

Comment: Oh yeah, so you are getting your proxy.php a text response and you are right, your server won't deal with php because it's designed to work with your vue files only.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes! That's the question I have been asking my self all the time. But the problem is, I do the developoment with the so called dev server, which I started with npm run serve. And this is not my own local apache server which I personally installed PHP. I am sure if I export my project and upload it to my own server. It may possibly work. The question is, how I can let the codes work when I am on dev server, which is created by the npm run serve

Comment: You can run a server for php and them run your npm run serve which will start a new server, so they will be running in different ports.

Comment: @AngelRoma Can you maybe give me a hint or link. Which I can read through and figure out how to do this? I have not done those options before and have no idea how to do it. Thanks for the advise though!

Comment: @MinXIE Sure!, Can I know if why you are running npm run serve? Is it because you installed the Vue framework or just serving a static site with any other npm package?

Comment: @Angel Roma Yep. I installed the vue framework and need to use it. So I do the npm run serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I placed the proxy.php file in the public/static folder and the vue-resource keeps getting the content of the proxy.php for me. But not go through it and return me the response.

In order to run your php files you will need to configure a local server to serve and execute php files because your `npm run serve` command is serving static files only. (Javascript, html, css and etc)

I suggest you to install a [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to easily configure a PHP development environment.

So you will get a local server for your php environment and another for your vue app running in different ports.

Comment: Than you very much! I followed your suggestion and configured a local apache server to run my proxy.php. So I can reach to my own apache server and use the php file! I now "again" go around the Cross Domain problem and I also put my solution in the question for other people who may has the same question I had.